# Weird issue installing Ruby on OSX 10.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, command-line, bash

I'm a beginner to command line, but I been have trouble trying to install Ruby for OS X 10.9.  [I follow the instruction from this site](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.9-mavericks) but when I get to the part that saids:

```
# Add rbenv to bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

I get this message:

> .bash_profile: Permission denied

My question is what I'm doing wrong and how to get it working right.
P.S. I did get Rails to work and I do have homebrew installed.

Comment: That's weird, you should have all permissions on your `.bash_profile`. Could you show us the output of `ls -l ~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: My guess is that might have created the .bash_profile with root and that's why now your user can't edit it, if when you do `ls -l ~/.bash_profile` like Amadan suggested, it shows that the user is root you should do a `sudo chown yourusername ~/.bash_profile` (your username is the one show in the terminal

Comment: -rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  54 Jun 22 22:21 /Users/blackbull77/.bash_profile

Comment: Yep, you need to chown your .bash_profile so that you (blackbull77) own it, not root.